# Frage über eine Wechselpräposition: Warten AUF...?

Tags: preposition

Ich habe soeben in einem Text folgendes gelesen

> Die zwei Mädchen müssen auf der Ampel warten.

Ich hatte immer gedacht, es wäre *warten auf + Akkusativ*, also habe ich in meinem Wörterbuch nachgeschlagen.

> an einem Ort, in einem Zustand, in einer Situation kürzere oder
> längere Zeit bleiben in der Annahme, im Hinblick darauf, dass etw.
> eintreten wird, was diese Situation ändert, beendet ⟨auf jmdn., etw.
> warten⟩
>
> > Beispiele: sie hatte vier Jahre auf den Verlobten, auf seine
> > Rückkehr gewartet (= hoffend bis zu seiner Rückkehr ausgeharrt) ich
> > werde auf dich warten

Aber hier ist Ampel Dativ.  Ist das vielleicht so, weil wir bei "die Ampel" uns auf einen *Ort* beziehen, nicht auf das, worauf wir warten? (Wie im ersten Beispiel oben). Das heißt, dass hier "auf" eine andere Rolle spielt als bei "warten auf", wo "auf" sich auf ein künftiges Ereignis bezieht?  In folgendem Satz wären dann die beiden Benutzungen zu sehen

> Die zwei Mädchen müssten **auf** der Ampel **auf** einen Autobus warten

Comment: *Die zwei Mädchen müssen auf der Ampel warten.* Ich würde noch einmal den Text kontrollieren. Da steht bestimmt etwas anderes.

Comment: "Ist das vielleicht so, weil wir bei "die Ampel" uns auf einen Ort beziehen, nicht auf das, worauf wir warten?" - das würde nur so funktionieren, wenn die Ampel ein Ort wäre, *auf* dem man warten kann. Sollten die zwei also nicht gerade auf den Ampelmast geklettert sein, ergibt das eher keinen Sinn und ich stimme dem obigen Kommentar zu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dual preposition should be dative not accusative](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58220/dual-preposition-should-be-dative-not-accusative)

Comment: @Olafant, Duplikate in verschiedenen Sprachen sollten nicht mit wegen des Schließgrunds *Duplicate* geschlossen werden. Siehe [hier](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-with-duplicate-questions-in-another-language), oder [hier](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/if-the-same-question-is-asked-in-german-and-english-is-it-a-duplicate).

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Stimmt! Danke für den Hinweis auf die verschiedenen Sprachen! Hatte ich übersehen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"warten auf + Akkusativ" bedeutet auf ein eintretendes Ereignis zu warten. Beispielsweise:

> Ich warte auf dein Kommen.

Hier "dich" statt "dein Kommen" zu sagen, ist meistens eine Kurzform davon - letztlich wartet man auf das Eintreffen der Person. Manchmal kann es auch bedeuten, daß auf eine bestimmte Aktion dieser Person gewartet wird:

> Du rufst A an und danach schreibe ich den Brief. Ich warte auf dich.

aber das ändert nichts daran, daß die Wendung im Akkusativ immer ein *Ereignis* darstellt, *auf das* man wartet.

Etwas grundlegend anderes ist, wenn der Grund für das Warten nicht genannt wird, sondern *der Ort*, an welchem es stattfindet. Dieser Ort steht tatsächlich - wie alle Ortsangaben - im Dativ, aber wohl eher "an" oder ähnlich:

> ich warte *an [vor, nach, hinter, bei, ...] der Ampel*

"auf der Ampel" zu warten ist zwar möglich, aber wäre mit reichlich Kletterei verbunden und vermutlich auch nicht ungefährlich - die meisten Ampeln und ihre Aufhängungen sind für das Beklettern nicht gemacht, schon gar nicht, wenn es zwei Personen sind. Sollte diese (ziemlich an den Haaren herbeigezogene) Bedeutung nicht gemeint sein, dann ist diese Formulierung schlicht FALSCH!

Möglicherweise heißt es aber auch

> warten auf *die* Ampel

Das wäre dann wieder Akkusativ und würde implizit bedeuten, daß zwar nicht auf *das Kommen der* Ampel gewartet wird (die ist vermutlich schon da), sondern auf deren Grünwerden, das Ende der Rotphase oder dergleichen. Besonders gelungener Stil wäre das meiner Meinung nach nicht, aber Stilfragen sind (auch) Geschmacksfragen.

Answer (score 1):

Da wir den Kontext nicht kennen, wissen wir nicht, ob der Satz in dem konkreten Fall richtig ist.

#### Auf etwas [Akkusativ] / eine Sache / ein Ereignis warten

Wenn man *auf etwas [Akkusativ] / eine Sache / ein Ereignis wartet*, dann wartet man auf das Erscheinen von etwas oder das Eintreten eines Ereignisses. Zum Beispiel:

> Die zwei Mädchen müssen *auf die (grüne) Ampel warten*.

Sie warten also, bis das Ereignis *„grüne Ampel“* eintritt.

#### Auf etwas [Dativ] / einer Sache / einem Platz warten

Wenn man *auf etwas [Dativ] / einer Sache / einem Platz wartet*, dann wartet man ganz einfach, während man sich auf etwas, auf der Sache, auf dem Platz befindet. Zum Beispiel:

> Zwei Mädchen sind auf eine Ampel geklettert und trauen sich nicht mehr herunter. Bis die Feuerwehr kommt, müssen sie *auf der Ampel warten*.

Hier beschreibt *auf der Ampel* den Ort, auf dem sie sich befinden, während sie warten.